# Can i using PnP script Update our custom list items "Status" field without affecting the ModifiedBy and Modifed fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp-powershell, pnp

we have a sharepoint online classic team site. and inside the classic team site, we have a custom list titled "Project Management" which have a custom drop down field named "ProjectStatus", which have 5 values such as; "Active", "In Progress", etc...

now i want to remap the "Project Management" list's items "ProjectStatus", as follow:-

1. if "ProjectStatus" = "Active" to map it as "Live".
2. if "ProjectStatus" = "In Progress" to map it as "not completed yet".

so can i run a PnP script to loop through all the list's items and update their statuses according to the above mapping? also not to affect the list items' modified date + modified by?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Get-PnPListItem` with CAML query to fetch the based on your conditions and then update them using `Set-PnPListItem` and passing the `SystemUpdate` parameter which wont change the modified and modified by fields.

You can modify from below sample code for Active projects :

```
$listItems= Get-PnPListItem -List "Project Management" -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ProjectStatus'/><Value Type='Text'>Active</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"

foreach ($item in $items)
{

    Set-PnPListItem -List $list -Identity $item.ID -Values @{"ProjectStatus" = "Live"} -SystemUpdate

}
```

You can repeat the same for Not completed projects by changing the caml query again running the code again.

Answer (score 2):

First, modify the column "ProjectStatus" values in list settings, change "Active" to "Live" and change "In Progress" to "not completed yet".

Then run the PnP PowerShell below.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lz -Credentials (Get-Credential)
$listName="Project Management"
$listItems= Get-PnPListItem -List $listName

foreach ($item in $listItems)
{
    if($item["ProjectStatus"] -eq "Active"){
        Set-PnPListItem -List $listName -Identity $item.ID -Values @{"ProjectStatus" = "Live"} -SystemUpdate
    }
    if($item["ProjectStatus"] -eq "In Progress"){
        Set-PnPListItem -List $listName -Identity $item.ID -Values @{"ProjectStatus" = "not completed yet"} -SystemUpdate
    }
}
```